# Realm Java fastest "BULK" write methodology

Tags: android, realm

I have the following code snippet mimic sqlite bulk insert for over 4000 transactions, I would like to know what should be the default  fastest and alternative best method to perform block writes to Realm memory or persist to Realm files without any expensive overhead loading ?

I am also not sure if I create a primary key  in the persist Realm files Tables,

obj=is the block info from the memory realm as shown by the  code snippet.

```
 Realm  realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
realm.beginTransaction();
 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj);  
realm.commitTransaction();
```

would automatically take care of new records creation with just one simple call or not ?

From the testing ,

Initiate with RealmObject 
 StkTBL stkTBL=new StkTBL()
 & CopyToRealm

seemed to be slightly faster than creating object such as 
 StkTBL stkTBL = realm.createObject(StkTBL.class);

In this example, StkTBl is the Realm Data Model without any primary key , source info is extracted from the CSV files before block writes to Realm in memory

```
    BufferedReader reader;

      TempConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                                .name("myTemprealm.realm")
                                .inMemory()
                                .build();

 Realm TempRealm = Realm.getInstance(TempConfig);
 TempRealm.beginTransaction();
 while ((txtline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 //skip code on extracting the relevant info from csv files
 //StkTBL stkTBL = realm.createObject(StkTBL.class);
 StkTBL stkTBL=new StkTBL();
 stkTBL.setSDate(IDate());
 stkTBL.setSOpen(open);
 stkTBL.setSHigh(high);
 stkTBL.setSLow(low);
 stkTBL.setSClose(close);
 stkTBL.setSVol(volume);
 stkTBL.setStk_symbol(mSymbol);                                
 StkTBL obj=TempRealm.copyToRealm(stkTBL);
     }
   TempRealm.commitTransaction();
   TempRealm.close();
```

Comment: Hi! Compared with using raw Realm underlying storage engine interface, java binding is slower because of all those JNI calls we cannot avoid :( I just checked the call routines of `StkTBL stkTBL=new StkTBL() & CopyToRealm` and `realm.createObject(StkTBL.class);` they should have exact same number of JNI calls which means they should almost have the same performance. I am wondering, according to your test, how "slightly faster" `StkTBL stkTBL=new StkTBL() & CopyToRealm` is? Thanks!

Comment: Hi , test result with 5k  suggest  vary by at least 1 to 2 seconds between those two write method  call , this lead me to believe it would be quite significant when transactions exceed 10k or higher , I am still searching for the default fastest write methods, any suggestion ?

Comment: One thing maybe you know, but I just want to confirm, when you are using `realm.createObject()`, the `copyToRealm` is just redundant. I suppose you did remove `copyToRealm` when do testing with `createObject`.

Comment: Hi , yes  mutually exclusive test is executed , not both  ,  it appeared that copyToRealm is using lesser overhead , I still would like to know is there any alternative way to speed up the block write to maximum since I just mimic sqlite "bulk insert" or may be just wait for the version 1.00 to become official

Comment: Two different write where   public <E extends RealmObject> List<E> copyToRealm(Iterable<E> objects) {
        if (objects == null) {
            return new ArrayList<E>();
        }

        ArrayList<E> realmObjects = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (E object : objects) {
            realmObjects.add(copyToRealm(object));
        }

        return realmObjects;
    }



    public <E extends RealmObject> E createObject(Class<E> clazz) {
        checkIfValid();
        Table table = getTable(clazz);
        long rowIndex = table.addEmptyRow();
        return get(clazz, rowIndex);
    }

Comment: Hi, I just created a issue in our github to track this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1684 . And i think there is not a perfect way to do this right now :(

Comment: Hi , thanks ,really appreciate ,hopefully official version 1 would  have new  api for bulk write.